# javascript - google map like image scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to build an image scroller that works like google map.  When the website first loads, there will be a viewing box in the middle of the page that contains part of an image.  A user can click and drag the image, that is scrolling, to inspect other areas of the image.  If the user happens to scroll beyond the perimeter of the image, the box will load an adjacent image.  I also want to overlay these images with markers that the user can click on to zoom in for more details.

Is there a library that does what I want already?  Or something close to what I want so that I can start to customize it?  Or if I have to build from scratch, any suggestions on the general approach to take?

I like using jquery library, so anything built with jquery would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Overscroll](https://plugins.jquery.com/overscroll/) jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this does everything you're looking for, but might be a good place to start: [SpryMap](http://candrews.net/blog/2010/10/introducing-sprymap/)

Comment: Also check [SpryMap demo](http://www.spidersoft.com.au/demo/sprymap/) and [code with IE fix on GitHub](https://github.com/slav123/SpryMap).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/) for projects similar to this and it works great!
Not based on jQuery though.

It provides free maps but you can have your own images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some design ideas to take into account when writing/finding your solution:

There are two ways of doing this, one with multiple chopped up images that preload when the user scrolls near them, and the other which is simpler and loads one big image.

If your image(s) are very big, you should opt for a solution that preloads segments as this will be a lot more user friendly if you can do it seamlessly.

The big image will slow down some computers/mobile devices significantly!

Answer (score 0):

If you built something yourself, it probably couldn't be pure jQuery. You'd want to write a server script that either processes your big images into segments that you cache, or serves segments on the fly. That's the point at which you could start using jQuery to control what gets loaded ans when.

Answer (score 0):

I think [CraftMap](http://www.jscraft.net/plugins/craftmap.html) seems to provide what you are asking for. But I'm unsure if it supports zooming.