# Google Map-like image zoom with loading slices of image on web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, zooming

I am looking for a relative-simple approach for one-level image zoom in, with slices of images loaded and appear as they are viewed in the area (like Google Maps). I have a lot of images, so manual-slicing maybe out of the question. Preferably no Flash/Silverlight.

I had look at some of the jQuery solutions but none quite fits what I am looking for.

Similar implementation can be seen on the UK National Gallery site ( http://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/paintings/georges-seurat-bathers-at-asnieres ), or the Google+ intro site ( http://www.google.com/+/demo/ )

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Overscroll plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/overscroll/), also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807449/javascript-google-map-like-image-scrolling). It should be trivial to make a script that slices up the images for you using something like [PHP's GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for responding late